# How can I integrate to a new workplace?

Tags: new-job, team

I have moved to a new job at a new country couple of weeks back (India to Singapore). This is all new for me. Company culture seems entirely different from the companies I worked before. I am having trouble fitting-in with company. I haven't made any new friends at new place (I am usually a very friendly person).

How can I navigate from here?

Comment: What is the new country? And, where did you moved from (your former country)? Sometimes, certain cultures are "colder" than others. It's also been a few weeks, and it's natural to take some time to adapt to big changes like this one.

Comment: I moved from India to Singapore.

Comment: Have you tried to make friends at work ? Do the native coworkers only talk to you about work in English strictly, and talk among themselves in their native language about other things such as social events, lunch, etc... ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can try:

1. Ask your manager for tips on how to make friends with local Singaporean coworkers whose native language is different from yours. The manager can give you some tips on understanding the local culture and socializing with the local people.
2. If your manager or a coworker invites the whole team to lunch, or to a coffee shop for a break, or to a social event both inside and outside the work environment, please go with the
   team.
3. Work hard, be friendly and ready to go an extra mile to help all
   coworkers when they request your help. They will appreciate your
   effort, and make great friends with you.
4. Find and make friends with coworkers who originally come from the
   same country as you. This way, they can help you to make new friends
   in the new country.
5. Outside work, also find and make friends with people who share the
   same culture and language as you do. They will help you out a lot.
6. Volunteer to help the local people outside work is also a good way to meet new
   people.

Comment: @Kilisi, I see your point. I meant to say the local Singaporean people. I know that the majority of Singaporeans are not from India, and have a different culture and native language from the Indian culture.

Answer (score 2):

Huge number of Indians in Singapore when I was there. Almost 10% of the population. You're best bet is to become friendly with some and learn from them.

The majority population is Chinese and they're probably very nice people to each other, but not so much to Indians from what I saw. I never really saw mixed groups eating together and they separated from each other in nightclubs and everywhere else as far as I noticed.

When relocating it's best to just keep your head down and concentrate on work, everything else comes with time. Just be pleasant to people and keep your eyes open. Don't make the mistake of being overly friendly.

Comment: "**The majority population is Chinese and they're probably very nice people to each other, but not so much to Indians from what I saw**". What do you think a Singaporean  on this forum would react to this statement... ? (BTW, I am not a Chinese or Singaporean).

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I have no idea, it's just an observation, but one backed by training in observing these sorts of scenarios. No offence is intended. There are similar social dynamics almost everywhere for those who understand what they're seeing. I liked Singapore, beautifully maintained place with impressive civil engineering.

Comment: I know that you would never intend to offend anyone or make someone feel uncomfortable. No worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand out:

How does company culture seem different from what you knew before?

Do you and your co-workers have other common languages but English? Since your use of English is not nearly native, how sure are you that that doesn't matter in this context?

When you have trouble fitting in, how does that show up or manifest itself? How far do you get before something goes wrong? When something does go wrong, how do you recognise the problem?